# Error 000725 using Points to Line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, points-to-line, error-000725

I'm consistently getting an error 000725 (Output Feature Class already exists) when trying to use the "points to line" tool in ArcMap 10.3

It's a points shapefile with 4 points and I just want to make them into a square outline. I've used this tool before and gotten this error, then rebooted my computer and it worked perfectly for multiple files for this exact same function. No luck this time.

I've rebooted, I've checked the "overwrite outputs" option under Geoprocessing options, I've created a new File Geodatabase in case the problem was that my default geodatabase was full. Now it's writing to a blank geodatabase, and being told to overwrite files, and STILL giving me the error that the file already exists. I've re-ordered my points within the shapefile to make sure they are in the correct order, I've tried converting my data to a shapefile through multiple avenues... I can't think of any other reason I'm getting this error.

I am using just the ArcToolbox:
Data Management Tools > Features > Points to Line.

My input feature is a points layer shapefile that is visible on the map and in the table of contents

I've quadruple-checked every time that the output file name doesn't already exist, so it is not actually an overwrite problem as far as I can understand. And I leave Line Field and Sort field blank.

I've also noticed a second error message, Runtime 999999, the coordinates or measures are out of bounds.

[image: Second Error Message]

[image: Command box and error message]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about how the site operates.  Would you be able to [edit] your question to include more precise details of your workflow, please?  For example, it sounds like you are using the Geoprocessing tool dialog to supply parameter values, but what are those values (a screenshot would help), and are you running this in the background or foreground, and while the dataset is represented by a layer in the table of contents or not?

Comment: Making a couple of assumptions: 1) You are using a personal geodatabase and 2) you are actually naming the output layer the same as another layer in the geodatabase (clues being: "checked overwrite outputs" and "being told to overwrite files")   I've encountered multiple errors trying to overwrite data using arcmap (from exporting a map .pdf to overwriting a layer) even when I check the box that I want to overwrite. My workaround is simply adding a prefix of suffix to the layer (usually a date increment layerX12092915, for example, so I know where to find the latest)

Comment: It is likely one of the layers in your map

Comment: Angela,  It is really convenient to export the results of your tool as a python snippet, then you can upload that snippet as a "code block" in an edit to this question above. That way we can all see what the GP Tool is doing.  Just pick one run (from the Results tab) and convert/share it please.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!
PolyGeo - Thank you, I've edited to description. It only takes about 20 seconds to run so I let it finish beofre moving on to anything else, is that what you mean by background/foreground?
MaryBeth - yes, that was what I thought, but I have been making new filenames every time to avoid this. I made a new File Geodatabase so that it would be saving to a blank geodatabase where duplicates would be impossible, and this didn't help either.

Comment: Python Snippet: # Replace a layer/table view name with a path to a dataset (which can be a layer file) or create the layer/table view within the script
# The following inputs are layers or table views: "STP10 selection"
arcpy.PointsToLine_management(Input_Features="STP10 selection", Output_Feature_Class="O:/Archaeo/Archaeo_ANCSA14h1/SheppardCollection/ArcGIS/Deadman Geodatabase.gdb/STP10_PointsToLine", Line_Field="", Sort_Field="", Close_Line="CLOSE")

Comment: Would you be able to save the 999999 error for a separate question, please?  It is a less likely one to get answered whereas it should be relatively easy to make progress on 000725.  By foreground/background I mean do you have the Enable checkbox (under Background Processing) marked on Geoprocessing | Geoprocessing Options.  I recommend that you leave it unmarked for this testing.  Would you be able to move that code snippet into your question so that you can take advantage of the `**{}**` button to format it, please?

Comment: I think you should use the [edit] button to revise your question so that it is a series of detailed steps that anyone trying to reproduce what you are seeing can follow.  These steps should begin at "Start ArcMap", and I suspect that by listing them, you will probably spot what is going astray, and if not, we will be in a much better position to offer targeted suggestions.